# What is the best way to implement CRUD functionality with pagination in a FlatList?

Tags: react-native, redux, pagination, redux-thunk, react-native-flatlist

I am currently building a very basic CRUD app in which users can seen post, delete, and update different recommendations. In the long term, it is best to use pagination rendering with lots of data just so I don't have to fetch a lot of recommendations at once.

I have an issue when I add or create a new recommendation. My app gets out of sync with my backend's pagination because it removes/adds an item from the database. What is the best way to implement the CRUD flow with a FlatList and Pagination?

Here is my recommendations reducer, actions, and FlatList:

Reducer:

```
import {
  SET_INITIAL_RECOMMENDATIONS,
  SET_NEXT_RECOMMENDATIONS,
  CREATE_RECOMMENDATION,
  UPDATE_RECOMMENDATION,
  DELETE_RECOMMENDATION,
} from "../actions/recommendations";

const recommendations = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_INITIAL_RECOMMENDATIONS:
      return action.recommendations;

    case SET_NEXT_RECOMMENDATIONS:
      return [...state, ...action.nextRecommendations];

    case CREATE_RECOMMENDATION:
      state.pop();
      return [action.recommendation, ...state];

    case UPDATE_RECOMMENDATION:
      const recommendationIndex = state.findIndex(
        (recommendation) => recommendation.id === action.recommendationId
      );
      const updatedRecommendations = [...state];
      updatedRecommendations[recommendationIndex] = action.recommendation;
      return updatedRecommendations;

    case DELETE_RECOMMENDATION:
      return state.filter(
        (recommendation) => recommendation.id !== action.recommendationId
      );
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default recommendations;
```

Actions:

```
export const fetchInitialRecommendations = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: IS_LOADING });
    fetch(`${BASE_URL}/recommendations?page=1`)
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((recommendations) => {
        dispatch({
          type: SET_INITIAL_RECOMMENDATIONS,
          recommendations: recommendations,
        });
        dispatch({ type: IS_NOT_LOADING });
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
};

export const fetchNextRecommendations = (pageNumber) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: RECOMMENDATIONS_ARE_LOADING });
    fetch(`${BASE_URL}/recommendations?page=${pageNumber}`)
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((recommendations) => {
        dispatch({
          type: SET_NEXT_RECOMMENDATIONS,
          nextRecommendations: recommendations,
        });
        dispatch({ type: RECOMMENDATIONS_ARE_NOT_LOADING });
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
};

export const deleteRecommendation = (recommendationId, navigation) => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const userToken = getState().loggedInUser.jwt;

    const reqObj = {
      method: "DELETE",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Berear ${userToken}`,
        Accepts: "application/json",
      },
    };

    fetch(`${BASE_URL}/recommendations/${recommendationId}`, reqObj)
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((data) => {
        if (data.status !== 200) {
          Alert.alert("Please Try Again.", data.error_messages[0], [
            { title: "OK" },
          ]);
        } else {
          dispatch({
            type: DELETE_RECOMMENDATION,
            recommendationId: recommendationId,
          });
          navigation.goBack();
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
};
```

My FlatList implementation:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  FlatList,
  ActivityIndicator,
  RefreshControl,
} from "react-native";

import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {
  fetchInitialRecommendations,
  refreshInitialRecommendations,
  fetchNextRecommendations,
} from "../../../store/actions/recommendations";

import RecommendationCard from "../../../components/UI/browser/recommendations/RecommendationCard";

import colors from "../../../constants/colors";

class BrowserRecommendationsScreen extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      page: 1,
      refreshing: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchInitialRecommendations();
  }

  handleRefresh = () => {
    this.setState({ refershing: true }, () =>
      this.props.refreshInitialRecommendations()
    );
    this.setState({ page: 1, refreshing: false });
  };

  loadMoreRecommendations = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        page: this.state.page + 1,
      },
      () => this.props.fetchNextRecommendations(this.state.page)
    );
  };

  newRecommedationOnPress = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("BrowserNewRecommendation");
  };

  render() {
    if (this.props.loader) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.activityIndicatorScreen}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color={colors.primaryColor} />
        </View>
      );
    }
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          contentContainerStyle={styles.flatList}
          data={this.props.recommendations}
          renderItem={(item) => (
            <RecommendationCard
              key={item.id}
              id={item.id}
              recommendationData={item}
              navigation={this.props.navigation}
            />
          )}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          refreshControl={
            <RefreshControl
              onRefresh={() => this.handleRefresh()}
              refreshing={this.props.recommendationsAreRefreshing}
            />
          }
          onEndReachedThreshold={0}
          onEndReached={this.loadMoreRecommendations}
          extraData={this.props.recommendations}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  activityIndicatorScreen: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: colors.secondaryLight,
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: colors.secondaryLight,
  },
  flatList: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    width: "100%",
    paddingBottom: 20,
  },
});

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    loader: state.loader,
    recommendationsAreLoading:
      state.recommendationsLoader.recommendationsAreLoading,
    recommendationsAreRefreshing:
      state.recommendationsLoader.recommendationsAreRefreshing,
    recommendations: state.recommendations,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    fetchInitialRecommendations: () => dispatch(fetchInitialRecommendations()),
    refreshInitialRecommendations: () =>
      dispatch(refreshInitialRecommendations()),
    fetchNextRecommendations: (pageNumber) =>
      dispatch(fetchNextRecommendations(pageNumber)),
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(BrowserRecommendationsScreen);
```

This goes back to my original question, what is the best way to implement CRUD functionality with FlatList and pagination? Or is there any work arounds? Thanks!

Comment: I have also noticed that when I keep scrolling down my this.state.page increases by 1. My back end is only rendering 4 recommendations per page.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, every time there is an action like edit, delete or add new item. I always load data from the begining (page 1) after I get response success from that action.

Comment: That’s a good alternative. But, wouldn’t that make the user scroll all the way up in the FlatList? I do not think that’s a good user experience.